# How should I remove leftover Python packages installed by pip using a previous version of Python?

Tags: python, pip

I'm running Fedora and use `pip install --user` to install Python packages. Some Fedora upgrades raise the minor Python version (e.g. 3.7 to 3.8), which leaves me with a directory like `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.7` that, as far as I understand, is of no use once I'm running Python 3.8+. Can I safely delete this directory, given that I haven't installed Python 3.7 (and don't intend to do so)? Or is there a better way of removing these old, now unused packages?

I presume the same thing happens whenever any OS upgrade preserves `$HOME` and updates Python. This has probably been answered before but I could find the right combination of search terms to find a definitive answer.

Comment: Sure. That dir is only contains the packages for `python3.7`. If you no longer have `python3.7`, there's no use for it

Comment: i suggest to post this question in ubuntu fourms/fedora fourms for better understanding, but from my personal experience, don't delete it, as some of your system application might depends on that python version

Comment: Rename the folder as a first step before you firmly commit to deleting it, but if any of your system applications depend on the contents of a home directory, as suggested by the previous comment, then you have a very broken system. I doubt that this is the case.